# Q: set thumbnail of a playlist?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

Many answers about using the Youtube Data API v3 to get the thumbnail of a playlist; and many answers for how to get or set the thumbnail of a video.

But none about how to set the thumbnail of a playlist. The documentation shows nothing and no searches into the API documentation or Stack Overflow find the question or its answers.

I tried using the `thumbnails().set()` method for setting thumbnails to videos, but that returns a permission denied error indicating that using playlist IDs in its request for video IDs is not a good monkey patch.

Please help.

Comment: Just to make sure: you agree that we can only set a video thumbnail as a playlist thumbnail ?

Comment: I do now. My question is invalid.

Comment: Are you anyway interested in an automated way to set the playlist thumbnail with a given video thumbnail of the playlist ?

Comment: I already have that answer from the user documentation on the Google Developer’s and YouTube Data API pages using thumbnails().set(). Though I do agree with what seems to be your implications— the Google Developer’s documentation can be so inconsistent and inaccessible. So unusual for such a cleanly run company I have long puzzled over it. Thank you for your consideration and concern to all users.

Answer (score 1):

My original question is invalid.

YouTube allows users to set thumbnails of videos to be any properly formatted image. YouTube then only allows users to set a specific video thumbnail as the playlist thumbnail. It is not possible to set an image as the thumbnail of the playlist unless it is a thumbnail of a video in that playlist; and in that use case the video is associated to the playlist for the representative thumbnail.

Comment: To some extent we can put an arbitrary thumbnail (at least from `PLAYLISTS` channel tab point of view), by adding the wanted thumbnail to the playlist, defining it as the thumbnail and then removing it. [`PL8wZFyWE1ZaJnJNqjC7xJI9bfVpN1UPjA`](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8wZFyWE1ZaJnJNqjC7xJI9bfVpN1UPjA) doesn't show a custom thumbnail but it does on [`@user-wl1ce4xg4j/playlists`](https://www.youtube.com/@user-wl1ce4xg4j/playlists)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if you are anyway interested in choosing the playlist thumbnail with a thumbnail video of the playlist in an automatic way:

Go to your playlist webpage: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLIST_ID

Open the Network tab of your web-browser by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Choose a video and "Set as playlist thumbnail".
You should now see a request to `edit_playlist`, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking).

You can re-execute this cURL request with any playlist id (`playlistId` in the `--data-raw` parameter) and any video id of the given playlist (`thumbnailVideoId`).